# How to use "learn you"

Tags: phrases, word-usage, literature, literary-english

While I was reading "The Adventures of Tom sawyer",I came across this phrase.

**Huck said ,"I will learn you."**

Is it right to say like that?Or we should say "I will learn from you"?

Comment: _I will teach you_ is the correct wording

Comment: It's nonstandard, and means, "I will teach you".

Comment: _"It ain't no use to try to learn you nothing, Huck.  Run along and
smouch the knivesthree of them."  So I done it._ is supposed to sound uneducated/dialect (oops, my example is from Huckleberry Finn)

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan! Is it grammatically correct to use "I will learn you" or it's just a local usage?

Comment: Completely incorrect. _I will teach you_ is correct

Comment: *Learn* and *teach* have opposing meanings: one person teaches - the second person learns. Just like: one person speaks - the second person listens.

Comment: @TrevorD Did you mean that phrase has a different meaning?

Comment: There's a related answer at http://english.stackexchange.com/a/113923/18696

Comment: Thanks @AndrewLeach ! I have read that...So it's considered vulgar and outdated to use this phrase in conversation.Right?

Comment: 'Vulgar' means offensive nowadays. But you are correct, it is outdated, very informal , and sounds like 'backwoods' speech. You will sound uneducated, or, as a non-native speaker, like you missed that class.

Comment: Thanks @Mitch..As a non-native speaker,it's difficult to understand many phrases in the classics..And I don't know whether we can use those phrases in conversation..Again thanks for clarification...

Comment: In response to "Did you mean that phrase has a different meaning?", I assume you mean the phrase "I will learn you". No, I meant the phrase is nonsense: The teacher will say "I will teach you."; the student will say "I will learn from you."  There are some Northern UK dialects that do use "learn you" to mean "teach you" - but (unless you are from that area) it should be avoided.

Comment: "Thanks !! I am clarified.": Say, "Thanks! I have it clarified." It is the issue that is clarified, not you.

Comment: I wonder, doctor,
Thou ask'st me such a question. Have I not been
Thy pupil long? *Hast thou not learn'd me how
To make perfumes?* distil? preserve? yea, so
That our great king himself doth woo me oft
For my confections?
—Shakespeare, Cymbeline, Act I, Scene 5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main characters in *The Adventures of Tom Sawyer* speak in a rustic, uneducated [vernacular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernacular), and while the book and its writing style are very entertaining, they should not be taken as a model for proper English usage.

Huck uses "I will learn you" to mean "I will teach you," a usage that was once a fairly common regionalism, but has since all but disappeared from the language (in fact, most people will probably never encounter it outside of the works of Twain). You should not use it yourself.

Comment: Thanks @phenry ,I will refer each phrase before using it...

Answer (score 2):

> 'Don't say "learn 'em," Toad,' said the Rat, greatly shocked. 'It's
>   not good English.'
>
> 'What are you always nagging at Toad for?' inquired the Badger, rather
>   peevishly. 'What's the matter with his English? It's the same what I
>   use myself, and if it's good enough for me, it ought to be good enough
>   for you!'
>
> 'I'm very sorry,' said the Rat humbly. 'Only I THINK it ought to be
>   "teach 'em," not "learn 'em."'
>
> 'But we don't WANT to teach 'em,' replied the Badger. 'We want to
>   LEARN 'em—learn 'em, learn 'em! And what's more, we're going to DO it,
>   too!'

*Wind in the Willows*, chap.11.
If it's good enough for Badger (in the right circumstances), it certainly is good enough for me.

Comment: It's not good enough for ***me**!* When it comes to English, I prefer it to be *"the same **as** I use myself"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: strictly, 'as *that which* I use myself', as Grahame well knew.  I am sorry you were greatly shocked.

Comment: @ Tim: The problem is *'as that which'* is a bit of a mouthful - it's never going to sound quite right in casual speech. I honestly don't know if Grahame's *'what'* reflects his age, class, or Scottish origins, but relatively speaking it's definitely a "minority" usage. There are hundreds of *the same what I use **myself*** in Google Books and only a few dozen for my ***as*** version. But almost all the ***what***'s are quoting this actual instance. Change *I/myself* to *we/ourselves* (or just discard *myself*), and it's obvious ***as*** is far more common overall.

Answer (score 0):

It is not incorrect but vulgar. It has a transitive sense like *He learned me how to write*.